# Error with grouped summary results when using likert()

Tags: r, plot, sjplot, likert

I am trying to visualise some Likert data. I have been successful doing this across all respondents using likert()

```
df <- data[,11:14]
df[] <- lapply(df, factor, 
               levels=c(1,2,3,4,5), 
               labels = c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral","Agree", "Strongly agree"))
df <- data.frame(df)
LK <- likert(df)
LK <- likert(summary = LK$results)

plot(LK, include.center=FALSE)+ggtitle("Title")
```

To cut this by group i have used the following code (which works):

```
LK2 <- likert(df, grouping = data$group)
str(LK2$results)

'data.frame':   34 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Group            : Factor w/ 9 levels "NSW","VIC", "QLD": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Item             : Factor w/ 4 levels "Question_1",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Strongly disagree: num  18.18 13.64 12.12 15.15 9.09 ...
 $ Disagree         : num  19.7 16.7 10.6 24.2 22.7 ...
 $ Neutral          : num  27.3 34.8 45.5 22.7 27.3 ...
 $ Agree            : num  24.2 22.7 18.2 24.2 24.2 ...
 $ Strongly agree   : num  10.6 12.1 13.6 13.6 16.7 ...
```

But then when i make a summary out of these results to plot:

```
LK3 <- likert(summary = LK2$results, grouping = LK2$results[,1])
str(LK3)

List of 5
 $ results :'data.frame':   28 obs. of  8 variables:
  ..$ Group            : Factor w/ 9 levels "NSW","VIC","QLD",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
  ..$ Group            : Factor w/ 9 levels "NSW","VIC","QLD",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
  ..$ Item             : Factor w/ 4 levels "Question_1",..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
  ..$ Strongly disagree: num [1:28] 16.22 16.22 8.11 18.92 14.29 ...
  ..$ Disagree         : num [1:28] 18.9 18.9 13.5 16.2 19 ...
  ..$ Neutral          : num [1:28] 35.1 27 48.6 21.6 42.9 ...
  ..$ Agree            : num [1:28] 16.2 24.3 13.5 29.7 19 ...
  ..$ Strongly agree   : num [1:28] 13.51 13.51 16.22 13.51 4.76 ...
 $ items   : NULL
 $ grouping: Factor w/ 9 levels "NSW","VIC","QLD",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ nlevels : num 6
 $ levels  : chr [1:6] "Item" "Strongly disagree" "Disagree" "Neutral" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "likert"
```

It seems to duplicate 'Group', and when i try to plot i get the following error message:

```
plot(LK3)

Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

No idea why this is happening - any help would be appreciated

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but what if you tried: `LK3 <- likert(summary = LK2$results[,-1], grouping = LK2$results[,1])`

Comment: @DaveArmstrong thanks - worked! Made my weekend...